# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Failed to load `http://localhost:8080/***`: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:8000`' is therefore not allowed access.
vue.esm.js?efeb:8566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: @Phil how is this a duplicate? The question could have been better, but there's a solution specific to vuejs.

Comment: @gyc a CORS issue has absolutely nothing to do with Vue other than the fact that JavaScript running in a browser initiated a cross-domain HTTP request. The answers in the linked post explain clearly what is required of the server in this kind of interaction

Comment: @Phil So you're saying the link to the duplicate will help him solve his CORs issues in his vue project?

Comment: @gyc the issues aren't in his Vue project. They're in whatever project is running on port 8080

Comment: I suppose this might help but only for running the local dev-server ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Comment: @Phil no this is wrong. He is on localhost, so just setting the correct headers in his requests will work. He needs to configure a proxy specific for his dev environment. Prod will come later.

Comment: @Phil finally you're trying to help a new contributor. Thanks.

Comment: @gyc any HTTP headers (other than Origin) to do with CORS are never set on the request